# what information does exactly Standard Report in Rally conveys?

Tags: rally

What exact information does this chart conveys?
[Standard Report](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/#!/example/standard-report)

It is pretty vague to say just defects and stories. Are the defects just the ones filed during this time period (Without caring about what "State" they are in?) Or this shows defects which in a certain state?

There is plethora of information on Rally's website, I agree, but it is scattered all over and hence, it gets really hard to do in even simple things using rally sdk.

@Kyle Here is my code for standard report with little modification. Even after adding extra parameters the standard Report chart remains the same as it was before adding those.

```
    _standardReport: function() {
    this.chartContainer.add({
                xtype:'rallystandardreport',
                project: Rally.util.Ref.getRelativeUri(this.getContext().getProject()),
                projectScopeUp: this.getContext().getProjectScopeUp(),
                projectScopeDown: this.getContext().getProjectScopeDown(),
                width: 600,
                height: 400,
                reportConfig: {
                    report: Rally.ui.report.StandardReport.Reports.Throughput,
                    work_items: 'G,D',
                    filter_field: 'ScheduleState',
                    from_state: 'Accepted',   <<<<<< added these
                    to_state: 'Accepted',      <<<<<<added these
                    DefectsByPriority: 'P1'   <<<<<< added these
                }
    });
},
```

Thanks
Kay

Answer (score 2):

Standard Report is a class of reports - those that are found on the Reports tab.  The particular one in the example is of a Throughput report.  More information about it can be found here:  https://help.rallydev.com/team-measurements?basehost=https://rally1.rallydev.com#through

Answer (score 0):

The StandardReport component basically is just a way to embed built-in reports from the Reports tab inside an app.

Here's an example of using it from the docs: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/example/standard-report

You can control which report to show and its various configuration parameters using the reportConfig:
https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.report.StandardReport-cfg-reportConfig

Comment: Is below the correct way to use report?                      reportConfig: {
                        report: Rally.ui.report.StandardReport.Reports.Throughput,
                        work_items: 'G,D',
                        filter_field: 'ScheduleState',
                        from_state: 'Accepted',
                        to_state: 'Accepted',
                        DefectsByPriority: 'P1'
                    }

Comment: That looks reasonably correct.  Do you get a chart to render?

Comment: When the "reportConfig" mentioned in my above config I see the chart render but it is no different then if I don't give "from_state," "to_state," "DefectsByPriority." I basically get the same chart that I got with the "StandardReport" config given on your website. Clearly, the extra things I added are not working.  Thanks! Kay

Comment: Can you update your original question with additional sample code so I can see the full configuration in your app?

Comment: I have edited my question to add the code.   Also, can you please comment on this question I am having a hard time trying to figure it out:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33743590/specifying-from-to-time-drop-down-calendar-in-rally-for-a-chart